# Abstract not showing up when removing \maketitle

Tags: titles, abstract, amsart

I have the code:

```
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}Some text \end{abstract}
\newpage
\section{some section}
```

But when I comment out `\maketitle` the document shows `\section{some section}`, not the abstract nor seem to use the command `\newpage` because "some section" is displayed on page 1.  When uncommenting `\maketitle` everything is displayed correctly.

How do I properly remove the maketitle and still having the abstract shown?

This example shows the issue (at least for me):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

%\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\section*{Acknowledgement}
Text 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `amsart` includes the `abstract` in the definition of `\maketitle`, and doesn't assume that the title or author can be empty/nonexistent, so space will always be left for them.  since `amsart` was designed to meet the specs for publication in ams journals, this is appropriate, if a nuisance when something different is wanted.  for the described situation, the best approach (other than choosing a different document class) is probably to redefine `\maketitle` to omit title and author.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both the abstract environment and the `\maketitle` command are defined by the document class. So, tell us at least which class you're using. Furthermore, post a small compilable example showing the problem. Here's such a compilable example using your piece of code but without problem, demonstrating that the cause must be somewhere else but not in those lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Test}
\author{Anonymous}
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\begin{abstract}Some text \end{abstract}
\newpage
\section{some section}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** in your edited post I can see you're using `amsart`. Here `\maketitle` is indeed required to show the abstract. But as a workaround you could use the internal command `\@setabstract`. Here it's inserted into your example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}

%\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}
\makeatletter
\@setabstract
\makeatother
\section*{Acknowledgement}
Text 

\end{document}
```

The output shows the abstract.

Answer (score 1):

If you clear the `\title` and `\author` fields, as you did in your minimal example, you can use `\maketitle` to output the abstract without any title headings.

Comment: Yes, that is an alternative (I am using it right now) but that trick aligns the abstract a bit too far down the page, I think.